# Why does my git commit affect both local and remote?

Tags: git, github, local, commit

So this happens...

Every time I want to do a commit it looks like it modifies both local and remote.

```
On branch Assessment_Read_SEG-58
Your branch and 'origin/Assessment_Read_SEG-58' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

I'm the only one working in this branch, and it always appears whenever I made a commit.
As far as I know this is all setup right:

```
Assessment_Read_SEG-58 tracked
KeyBehaviour           tracked
Login                  tracked
development            tracked
master                 tracked
roles                  tracked
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
Assessment_Read_SEG-58 merges with remote Assessment_Read_SEG-58
development            merges with remote development
Local refs configured for 'git push':
Assessment_Read_SEG-58 pushes to Assessment_Read_SEG-58 (local out of date)
development            pushes to development            (up to date)
```

right?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the output of status.  That means you have done a `fetch` and don't have one of your upstream commits in your local branch.  use `merge` or `rebase` to get it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I had a colleague solve it. We could not find the reason exactly but it now works fine again. He did some rebasing to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved by a colleague and had probable something to do with with a accidental merge where I was missing some commit. I'm not experienced enough with git to explain the details but breaking it all up beyond the point of the merge fixed it.